# Create extended entry along side user entry django

Tags: python, django, forms

Hi Thanks for your help

I have the code below that is working to create a new user when the "user_profile" part is commented out. I am just trying to add the extended fields to the user. I think im close but im a little lost. Whats the correct way of doing this?

right now when i run it uncommented i get this error

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: slug_trade_app_userprofile.user_id
```

to be clear, before clicking submit that user does not exist in the database

views.py

```
def signup(request):

if request.method == 'POST':

    user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid():

        if user_form.is_valid():
            print("1")
            #user
            created_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            created_user.username = created_user.email
            created_user.set_password(created_user.password)
            created_user.save()
            print("2")

            #extended profile
            created_profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            created_profile.user = created_user
            created_profile.save()
            print("3")
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/profile_pictures', blank=True )
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    on_off_campus = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                            default="on",
                            choices=CAMPUS_STATUS)
```

Another way ive tried to make this work is below. I'd like to do it the more Django correct way but either way is ok. I get the same error both ways.

```
def signup(request):

if request.method == 'POST':

    user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid():


        # create user
        username = request.POST['email']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password1']

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,
                            first_name=first_name,
                            last_name=last_name,
                            email=email,
                            password=password)

        #extended
        bio = request.POST['bio']
        on_off_campus = request.POST['on_off_campus']

        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create( user=user,
                            bio=bio,
                            on_off_campus=on_off_campus)
```

Comment: Since you changed the whole code snippet, could you also fix indentation?

Comment: fixed..........